# table responsive using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Actually I have a table with seven columns,in that three are with large text and remaining four are with icons.The problem is when I am making responsiveness by using bootstrap class "table-responsive",for the tab device responsiveness it is showing the all the columns of equal width,but I expect to be the the three columns with text should occupy more width than the icons columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- use class table-responsive to parent div of table
- use class table to table element
- give particular width to th/td's

Answer (score 0):

Add `width=""` attribute to your table `<th>`s.

Answer (score 0):

on the `th` column you can add

```
class="col-sm-4" //or larger try it for the 3 fonts columns
```

and

```
class="col-sm-1" //or smaller try it for the 4 icon columns
```

or something like that